# Can I disable Google Contacts' new search everywhere feature?

Tags: google-contacts

Google Contacts preview searches everywhere when you search your contacts.  I find it makes it very difficult to search my own contacts because of the feature.  Is there a way to disable it?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like it, no. I'd have expected some sort of search operator (`in:my-contacts` perhaps?) but it doesn't look like they have any. It is a preview, after all.

Your recourse is probably to go back to the existing contacts manager.

I'd suggest, at least, using the "Send feedback" tool to let Google know that you would like to see changes to the search.

Comment: Agreed. Sorry, I didn't read past the first two sentences before adding an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Opt out of the new Google Contacts Preview. That will fix search!

Also, use the Send Feedback feature to report how the Preview search doesn't work for you. With enough reports and anecdotes, the team will understand.